# Differences between python and flutter in requests

Tags: python, flutter, python-requests

I am kind of new to Flutter. Want to make Flutter web app that I already made by Python.
I was doing all good but got strange error. that I don't understand.

Here is Flutter code

```
flutter==3.7.0
http: ^0.13.4

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

var headers ={
      'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36',
      'referer': 'https://datalab.naver.com/shoppingInsight/sCategory.naver'
      };
var response = await http.get(Uri.parse("https://datalab.naver.com/shoppingInsight/getCategoryKeywordRank.naver?cid=50000000&timeUnit=date&startDate=2023-02-21&endDate=2023-03-21&device=&page=1&count=20"), headers: headers);
print(response.body);
```

And here is Python code

```py
python==3.9
requests==2.26.0

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36',
    'referer': 'https://datalab.naver.com/shoppingInsight/sCategory.naver'
}
response = requests.get('https://datalab.naver.com/shoppingInsight/getCategoryKeywordRank.naver?cid=50000000&timeUnit=date&startDate=2023-02-21&endDate=2023-03-21&device=&page=1&count=20',
                        headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

Python code works just fine. but Flutter returns with wrong html that says "Page not found". it should return with json data.

So i guess that Python's and Flutter's requests works differently. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this with dio package

```
var dioInstance = Dio();
dioInstance.options.headers = {
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36',
  'referer': 'https://datalab.naver.com/shoppingInsight/sCategory.naver'
};
var responseDio = await dioInstance.get("https://datalab.naver.com/shoppingInsight/getCategoryKeywordRank.naver?cid=50000000&timeUnit=date&startDate=2023-02-21&endDate=2023-03-21&device=&page=1&count=20");
print(responseDio.data);
```